# What is the smallest value of the expresion $\sqrt{a^2 +9}+\sqrt{(b-a)^2+4}+\sqrt{(8-b)^2 +16}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can you find the smallest possible value of $\sqrt{a^2 +9}+\sqrt{(b-a)^2+4}+\sqrt{(8-b)^2 +16}$ using only algebra or analytic geometry.

I guessed that it would be the value when $a=0,b=8$ as then the first and third terms would have smallest values but am unable to prove it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean integer values?

Comment: a,b are real numbers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: This is the sum of the distances from $(0,0)$ to $(a,3)$ to $(b,5)$ to $(8,9)$. Pick $a$ and $b$ so these are all on a line.

Comment: Why would having all these points on a line minimize the sum of the distances?

Comment: I would have thought that making the points $(a,3)$ and $(b,5)$ as close to one another as possible would minimize the sum?

Comment: due to the triangle inequality

Comment: The shortest path between two points ($(0,0)$ and $(8,9)$ here) is a line. @Mufasa

Comment: Got it! thx @ThomasAndrews